# How to run 'php artisan queue:listen' on Openshift so that it runs every time someone uses the application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, openshift

I actually have a mailing system that I want to implement using queues in Laravel. Every time an order is placed, the customer should receive a mail.

I used

```
Mail::queue('mail.view',$data,function($message){
    $message->to($email,$name)->subject('Order Confirmed.');
}
```

Then, I run `php artisan queue:work` to actually process the queue. How can I automate the work?
I'm using Openshift for hosting.

According to [Laravel Coding](http://laravelcoding.com/blog/laravel-5-beauty-sending-mail-and-using-queues), a way of doing this is

> One is load up `artisan queue:listen` in the startup scripts of your server. This command automatically calls artisan queue:work when items appear in the queue.

How do I add `artisan queue:listen` to startup scripts?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using the [OpenShift Laravel 5 QuickStart](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/115-laravel-5-0)...

After line #91 in the `.openshift/action_hooks/deploy` file, add a call to `artisan queue:listen`:

```
php artisan migrate --force
php artisan queue:listen
```

Comment: But, I'm getting errors when I did that.
So, instead I used cron jobs on a minutely basis and used `queue:work` instead.
Thanks!